# Intellij Idea - Android Studio Plugin - Build Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

from 5 months ago I use Intellij Idea CE to develop an android studio **plugin**

but

after Android studio latest update

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 26, 2021
```

my plugin does not work anymore

I update Intellij Idea CE to match the android studio version, then when I tried to build my plugin again

build failed and show me this error

```
Execution failed for task ':instrumentCode'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration3'.
   > Could not find com.jetbrains.intellij.java:java-compiler-ant-tasks:203.7717.56.2031.7583922.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/jetbrains/intellij/java/java-compiler-ant-tasks/203.7717.56.2031.7583922/java-compiler-ant-tasks-203.7717.56.2031.7583922.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/jetbrains/intellij/java/java-compiler-ant-tasks/203.7717.56.2031.7583922/java-compiler-ant-tasks-203.7717.56.2031.7583922.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jetbrains/intellij/java/java-compiler-ant-tasks/203.7717.56.2031.7583922/java-compiler-ant-tasks-203.7717.56.2031.7583922.pom
```

here is my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.6.4'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.21'
}

group 'com.myplugin'
version '1.5.7'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}


apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.intellij'
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.21'

}


// See https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/

intellij {
    version = '2020.3.3'
    plugins = ['android']
    localPath 'ANDROID STUDIO PATH'
    updateSinceUntilBuild = false
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

**How to fix it .??**

Comment: does this help? https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/issues/369

Comment: I saw this link 
but the last comment on this issue refer to my current issue
https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/issues/369#issuecomment-890726161

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As gradle-intellij-plugin doesn't support Android Studio natively, it doesn't know what compiler version should be used for local AS SDK, and it tries to compiler with the same version as AS, which does not exist. To fix that, you need to specify a particular compiler version explicitly using [instrumenting dsl](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin#instrumenting-dsl).

All available versions are listed in [intellij maven repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases). In your case, I think 203.7717.56 would be just fine.

So the configuration should look like this:

```
tasks {
  instrumentCode {
    compilerVersion = "203.7707.56"
  }    
}
```

Comment: it will be
`compilerVersion = "203.7717.56"`
but anyway
thank you so much